# StartTimePicker set time(android)

Tags: java, android, time

Sorry for my english. I want if click textView open dialog and set time(24h), but i cant get value. Log.e output nothing

```
time.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new StartTimePicker();
                dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "start_t_picker");
            }
        });

//code
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
        class StartTimePicker extends DialogFragment implements OnTimeSetListener{

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Send.this, null, hour, min, true);

                return dialog;
            }


            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                Log.e("time is", String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your onCreateDialog() method like this

```
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Send.this, this, hour, min, true);

                return dialog;
            }
```